# Bounding a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe 'dayData' and I'm trying to bound a column 'second_step' in the dataframe (writing the result to a new column called (very originally) 'third_step').  The data looks like:

```
   second_step
0     0.185185
1     0.148148
2     0.148148
3            0
4     0.185185
5            0
6            0
7            0
8     0.148148
9     0.185185
10           0
```

using the line:

```
dayData["third_step"] = max(min(dayData["second_step"],2),-2)
```

However I get an exception:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What does this mean? The datatype is a dataframe (`Type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`) and I'm rather confused.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use vectorized functions for that - it should be faster compared to `apply()` approach:

```
df['third_tep'] = np.where(np.abs(df.second_step) > 2, np.sign(df.second_step) * 2, df.second_step)

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
    second_step  third_tep
0      0.185185   0.185185
1      0.148148   0.148148
2      0.148148   0.148148
3      6.000000   2.000000
4      0.185185   0.185185
5      0.000000   0.000000
6     -5.000000  -2.000000
7      0.000000   0.000000
8      0.148148   0.148148
9      0.185185   0.185185
10     0.000000   0.000000
```

**Timing** against 1.1M rows DF:

```
In [44]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [45]: df.shape
Out[45]: (1100000, 2)

In [47]:  %timeit df.second_step.apply(bounded)
1 loop, best of 3: 996 ms per loop

In [48]: %timeit np.where(np.abs(df.second_step) > 2, np.sign(df.second_step) * 2, df.second_step)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion**: vectorized approach was approx. 61 times faster...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply`

```
bounded = lambda x: max(min(x, 2), -2)
dayData["third_step"] = dayData.second_step.apply(bounded)
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a pandas method to do this, [`clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
In [6]:
df['third_step'] = df['second_step'].clip(-.1,.1)
df

Out[6]:
    second_step  third_step
0      0.185185         0.1
1      0.148148         0.1
2      0.148148         0.1
3      0.000000         0.0
4      0.185185         0.1
5      0.000000         0.0
6      0.000000         0.0
7      0.000000         0.0
8      0.148148         0.1
9      0.185185         0.1
10     0.000000         0.0
```

**timings**

```
In [11]:
%timeit np.where(np.abs(df.second_step) > 2, np.sign(df.second_step) * 2, df.second_step)

10 loops, best of 3: 28.9 ms per loop

In [12]:    
%timeit df['second_step'].clip(-.1,.1)

10 loops, best of 3: 51.2 ms per loop
```

This is nearly 2x slower than the pure numpy method which is not surprising as pandas methods perform additional stuff like type and bounds checking